# Long then when counting all recoreds where one field is not null

Tags: mysql

I got mysql db ,
runing this query `select count(*) from items` takes 9s and returns oround 2m rows
but when I add one condition like `select count(*) from itemswhere clientid is not null` it runs 60s , is it possible to add some index to speed it up ?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COUNT(clientid) FROM items` will actually do what you want because `count` does not count null values.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a count of all records, there's no need to do a `COUNT()` on all fields, i.e. `*`.

Try perform the `COUNT()` on just the primary key, or a similar field.

e.g.

`SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM items WHERE clientid IN NOT NULL`